# Airflow dag_run.conf

Tags: python, airflow

Hi I am getting an issue in the below code since the variable is always treated as a string, string does not have get method

```
def evaluate(elastic_environ: Any) 

 elastic_loader_mode = '{{dag_run.conf}}'
 airflow_config_expected = {"elastic_mode": "full"}

if bool(elastic_loader_mode):
    if "elastic_mode" in elastic_loader_mode.keys() and "full" in elastic_loader_mode.values():
   print('full')
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Expected config {airflow_config_expected}, but got {elastic_loader_mode}")
else:
    print('delta')
```

Comment: Can you share the full dag?  I think you are calling it iutside a task and thats the reason.

Comment: yes it is within a separate function, but I do get the value in this task

Comment: if its in task (PythonOperator for example) then you should get the dag_run.conf from the context. I can help much more if I'll see the code

Comment: The problem is not that I am not getting the value but that the declaration that elastic_loader_mode = '{{dag_run.conf}}' treats it as a string but in fact a dictionary is returned. The dag complains saying string doesn#t have .keys()

Comment: add "render_template_as_native_obj=True" to your dag declaration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help OZS but it seems to have no effect

Comment: what is the value of "elastic_loader_mode" if you print it after the assignment?

Comment: It can be either {"elastic_mode": "full"} or an empty dictionary

Comment: I have a similar situation where I need to get the dag_run.conf as a dict and not as a string value. Its frustrating that the dag errors out if we have an optional attribute not present in our config since we cannot check prior to "{{ dag_run.conf["attribute"] }}. Any workaround yet ? the "render_template_as_native_obj=True" does not work for me either. Assuming its Jinja, I also tried to give it a default value using "| default('Default_Val')" but to no effect